# How to add the exception for the function?

Tags: plsql

```
FUNCTION XX_GETSAL(N_ENO NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    N_SALARY NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SAL INTO N_SALARY FROM XX_TBEMP WHERE ENO = N_ENO;
    RETURN N_SALARY;
    COMMIT;
  END;
```

in this function i would like to add the exceptional cases i.e when i gave the eno number which is not available in the table it has to give me the exception condtion HOW CAN WE ADD THAT

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (for example):

```
  FUNCTION XX_GETSAL(N_ENO NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    N_SALARY NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SAL INTO N_SALARY FROM XX_TBEMP WHERE ENO = N_ENO;
    RETURN N_SALARY;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN NULL;
  END;
```

(NB `COMMIT` has no place in this function.)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a slight modification to the above code in that since the function returns a number, you can choose to return a number that signifies the `NO_DATA_FOUND` condition (e.g. I chose -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XX_GETSAL(N_ENO NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    N_SALARY NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SAL INTO N_SALARY FROM XX_TBEMP WHERE ENO = N_ENO;
    RETURN N_SALARY;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN -1;
END;
```

I added the `CREATE OR REPLACE` to the code as well.
Just my take on it.